# Solr sunspot search on models having fields with same name not working

Tags: solr, lucene, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have two models `Posts` and `Comment` both have `title`,`description` fields for which i have set `text`,`ngram` fieldtypes and fields with text type give me results but fields with ngram type does not give me any results

my models are like

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title, :boost => 5
    text :title_ngram, :boost => 2
    text :description, :boost => 2
    text :description_ngram, :boost => 2
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title, :boost => 5
    text :title_ngram, :boost => 2
    text :description, :boost => 2
    text :description_ngram, :boost => 2
  end
end
```

when i check schema browser in back-end i see that `title_ngram` and `description_ngram` has been added but when i click on load terms it shows nothing (which i think is the reason for this issue)